# function fzero, matlab , internal rate of return , complex roots

Tags: matlab

I am trying to calculate the internal rate of return without using the "irr" function: A is the cash flow, and I am trying to find the value of x that makes the net present value = 0.

```
A = [-1000 100 900 100 -100 -400];
[xval, fval]=fzero(@(x) A*((1+x).^-(0:length(A)-1))'  , 0 )  ;
```

The correct result should be x=-2, while the fzero returns [xval, fval]=[-1, 2.315841784746324e+79]

I guess that this has something to do with complex roots. Searching in the guide I cannot find how to restrict results to real roots (admitting that this is actually the problem).

Does anyone understand what is going on and how to get the desided result?

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. Can you suggest a strategy to identify multiple roots? Would it be useful to use symbolic calculation to avoid this kind of problems ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fzero look for sign inversion and not exactly 0. If you plot the function:
[image: plot of your function]

you see that the sign inversion occurs around -1 and you ask the function to look over 0.

if you change the value of X0 from 0 to -5 for example:

[xval, fval]=fzero(@(x) A*((1+x).^-(0:length(A)-1))'  , -5 )  ;

then you will have the xval = -2

Answer (score 1):

Taking a value to a negative power is pretty much guaranteed to return complex values, don't you think? You can try wraping  your function with [`real`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/real.html) to force the result to be real-valued:

```
A = [-1000 100 900 100 -100 -400];
[xval,fval] = fzero(@(x)real(A*(1+x).^-(0:length(A)-1).'), 0);
```

which returns `-1.000000000000000`. This function has multiple roots. If you want the `-2` root, you'll have to choose an initial guess nearer to or on the other side of `-2`, e.g.,

```
[xval,fval] = fzero(@(x)real(A*(1+x).^-(0:length(A)-1).'), -3);
```